# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No WireType for value

Tags: java, android, square-wire

use `com.squareup.wire wire-runtime`.

code:

```
Wire wire = new Wire();
VerifyTicketRsp ticketRsp = wire.parseFrom(moaResult.objectBytes, VerifyTicketRsp.class);
```

error info:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No WireType for value 118
  at com.squareup.wire.WireType.valueOf(WireType.java:36) 
  at com.squareup.wire.MessageAdapter.read(MessageAdapter.java:521) 
  at com.squareup.wire.Wire.parseFrom(Wire.java:144) 
  at com.squareup.wire.Wire.parseFrom(Wire.java:135)
```

Note: this code run on 99% device work fine. But sometimes get this error, the probability is 1/100000. Anyone knows ?

Comment: What's the type of `moaResult.objectBytes`?

Comment: moaResult.objectBytes is ByteInputStream